# How can i use z-index with overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some content in it. I want to add a show more button with fade effect but the button gets behind the div when i am using z-index combined with overflow hidden.

Problem:

[image: Problem]

Desired Result:
[image: Desired result]

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 16rem;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1em;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  //some content
</div>
<button class="btn">Show more</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a box and have one for the content like this, that also means keep the button in that box as well.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}

.box__content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 16rem;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1em;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__content">
    blandit nullam nascetur vitae ipsum quis non parturient, id ullamcorper quam maximus scelerisque facilisis amet tincidunt. Nec curabitur elit vehicula magna dolor convallis, commodo fusce accumsan phasellus vestibulum senectus, efficitur elementum netus
    luctus pellentesque. Leo hendrerit rutrum ac facilisi nullam sapien consectetur, proin amet lobortis ultricies primis nec torquent dis, orci nisi class ridiculus lacinia dui. Euismod suspendisse ad maximus ut nibh urna ante nascetur tellus, penatibus
    fermentum eleifend faucibus scelerisque nisi fames ornare eget curae, nec eu ex ultricies potenti bibendum pellentesque mattis. Magnis lorem curabitur neque urna rhoncus sit, turpis varius facilisi nascetur elit cursus maximus, justo phasellus eros
    posuere netus.
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Show more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using `flexbox` and wrap all elements in a `wrapper`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;         /* Set as per your requirement */
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  flex-basis: 16rem;  /* Set as per your requirement */
  background-color: red;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  top: -1rem;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    //some content
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Show more</button>
</div>
```